# Radius of Mac OS X Windows?

Tags: mac, osx

What is the corner radius of the windows in Mac OS X? I kind of like to have stuff right on the dot and it'll bug me until I find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a hand-made measurement, the corner radius seems to be 7px. Plus 1 px, if you include the left drop shadow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it seems to be more like 5px.

The black around the window (I used a Finder.app window for that, to ensure that I have a native one) is the rim shadow from Mojave's dark mode which makes for a pretty good guideline for the orange border I placed.

I experimented with 4px and 6px, but 5px seems to hit the mark best.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ubuntudroid, do you have a source for that? you can [edit] your answer to add more info. Also, feel free to stick around, answer more questions and maybe ask a question of your own.

Comment: Hi @PieBie, just tried it out manually by trying to put a rounded rectangle around some windows. 4px radius worked best for all the windows I tried.

Comment: Could you maybe add a screenshot of that, like Yisela did?

Comment: @PieBie done, also changed my response to 5px as this seems to be closer to reality.